# rails controller creating instead of updating when passing in an id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to add a file to a model using qqfile (though that really isn't relevant here).

I look at the params being passed to the server for update, and I have

```
{ id: 63, photo: 'foto_file.jpg'}
```

My understanding was that if an object was passed with an id parameter, rails would understand that as an already existing object, and update that model. If no id parameter is present, Rails would use create.

Is that not correct?? How in this instance can I tell rails to update rather than create?
I'm assuming more code isn't needed here, as my controllers won't really help with the solution because I think the decision is made by rails before it really hits the controller. But I'm happy to post the controller code if it is needed.

--------------- my javascript used to update or create the model ---------------------

```
render: function(){
        var start_form=HandlebarsTemplates['user/userForm'](user.attributes);
        $(this.el).html(start_form);

        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('file-upload'),
            action: '/users',
            onSubmit: function(id, fileName){

                if(MyApp.user.id){
                 uploader.setParams({
                    id: MyApp.user.id
                    });
                }
            },
            debug: true
        });


    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `update` method is only used when you sent a `PUT` request, not a `POST` request. Make sure you're using the `PUT` method. (If you show your form's code, I can give a more specific answer).

**Update** -- With your code, try adding this as a parameter to your `qq.FileUploader` call:

```
params: {
  _method: "put"
}
```

Rails will look for a `_method` parameter to handle PUT/DELETE requests.

Comment: thanks Dylan, I added the code. I'm using backbone, so it is javascript code to submit. I tried to find a qqfile example using PUT or POST, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Updated with a possible solution.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work Dylan, I'm still getting new models created. I tried without the `_` but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get Dylan's javascript method to work, so in my controller I redirected to my update if the response had an id.

```
def create
   if params[:id]
      return self.update
   end
   #then all my regular create stuff here
end

def update
   #all the usual update stuff
end
```